# Selecting a .class inside an .id - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am the newest person to javascript and I have an .class inside a couple of Div.id's and am unable to access the id successfully with my .css formatting. Here is my structure.

```
<div id="mainColumn">
 <div id="SpotlightContainer">
   <div id="SpotlightText">
    <div class="Title"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

here is how I try to acces it in JQuery,

```
$('div.mainColumn div.SpotlightContainer  div.SpotlightText  div.Title').html(data[0].title);
```

I can see the data[0].title coming through in Chrome, so I know that isn't the issue. 
Can someone please point out where I am going wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An [id selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#id-selectors) starts with a `#` not a `.` (which is for a [class selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#class-html)).

Answer (score 2):

You're prefixing IDs with `.`, but that's for classes. IDs are prefixed with `#`. You could also use a simpler selector:

```
$('#mainColumn .Title')
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS selector for `id` is `#`. Your query should be `'#mainColumn #SpotlightContainer  #SpotlightText div.Title'`

Answer (score 1):

Will work ('#' is an id selector. '.' is a class selector!):

`$('div#mainColumn div#SpotlightContainer div#SpotlightText div.Title')`

However, that selector string will work through any number of children in the hiearchy, independently of how many layers down the child was found. To be more strongly typed, you could specify that the child must be the first child:

`$('div#mainColumn > div#SpotlightContainer > div#SpotlightText > div.Title')`

..**or** keep using the whitespace and do not depend on the structure inbetween your elements:

`$('div#mainColumn div.Title')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $('#mainColumn #SpotlightContainer #SpotlightText .Title');
```

"#" is used to select id and "." is used to select class.